# This Form of method call only allowed for class methods error

Tags: delphi

I keep getting this error. On `FGetZoneData` I have:

```
var
   SelectedDept: String;

implementation

procedure TFGetZoneDept.GetClick1(Sender: TObject);
var
  azone: string;
  adept: string;
  bstats,
  bname,
  btop,
  bleft,
  bnumber,
  basset: string;
  machine : TMachine;
begin
  fdb.count := 0;  //keeps track of number of machines in zone
  azone := Combobox1.Text;    //gets name of zone
  adept := TfDB.GetDeptDBName(SelectedDept); //gets name of dept from a function
  fdeptlayout.ListBox1.Clear;
end;
```

and on `TFdB` I have a function declared in public:

```
public
    Function GetDeptDBName(name :string):String;
end;
```

Any idea why this would not work?

Comment: call `adept := fdb.GetDeptDBName()` instead. Calling `TfDB.GetDeptDBName()` assumes a class method.

Comment: thanks make answer and i can accept... not sure how i missed that..but i guess it happens

Comment: ain has answered correctly already. No need to duplicate his answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're calling the method on a class (I assume `TfDB` is a class name) not on an instance. Only [class methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Class_Methods) can be called that way. What you have to do is to create an instance, then call the method on it:

```
var DB: TfDB;
begin
  DB := TfDB.Create(); // create an instance
  adept := DB.GetDeptDBName(SelectedDept); // call the method
```

See the [E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/E2076_This_form_of_method_call_only_allowed_for_class_methods_%28Delphi%29) topic in docwiki.